# How to change proximity of user location annotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mapkitannotation

How to change the proximity of which a `userLocation annotation` generates.
[image]
I'm talking about the faded blue circle the `userLocation annotation` is creating around it. How can I change it's radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView

Add following files from Library:

```
SVAnnotation.h
SVAnnotation.m

SVPulsingAnnotationView.h
SVPulsingAnnotationView.m
```

Import:

```
#import "SVAnnotation.h"
#import "SVPulsingAnnotationView.h"
```

Using `SVPulsingAnnotationView` you can set `pulseScaleFactor` property to change radius,use below code in `viewForAnnotation` method when you found UserLocation:

```
        static NSString *identifier = @"currentLocation";
        SVPulsingAnnotationView *pulsingView = (SVPulsingAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if(pulsingView == nil) {
            pulsingView = [[SVPulsingAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            pulsingView.annotationColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.678431 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
            pulsingView.pulseScaleFactor=7.0;//Change pulseScaleFactor as required
            pulsingView.canShowCallout = YES;
        }

        return pulsingView;
```

Comment: will it be intractable? Like when the proximity will hit an annotation it'll do something?

Comment: yes, as it implements `@interface SVPulsingAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView`@Talha Ch

Comment: I implemented it as you said first of all I used pods to include this library. Then it showed me error that this is not found `#import "SVAnnotation.h"` after that in the code `pulseScaleFactor` is not found. What to do?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/phunware/maas-mapping-ios-sdk based on the search for `pulseScaleFactor` will it work?

Comment: `SVAnnotation.h` and `SVAnnotation.m` will be in library at above given link and you have to add it into your project@TalhaCh

Comment: I've figured out the way to increase the pulse scale factor and I'm close to what I want to achieve. I did it without importing `SVAnnotation.h` and with only `SVPulsingAnnotationView.h`. But there is one thing I can't find so can you edit your answer and show me that if I've added a custom annotation and if the pulse hits it it'll do something like show an alert or something.

Comment: can you answer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479964/annotations-get-pop-up-when-user-is-near-them

Comment: i can't figure it out, but you can check [https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/32piou/mapkit_annotations_closing_on_didupdatelocation/](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/32piou/mapkit_annotations_closing_on_didupdatelocation/) it may help@TalhaCh